# How to dynamically assign a variable to sequentually named textboxes in VBA for Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tbxInvites0 ... tbxInvites6.  I would like to create a for loop which will increment the tbxInvites# and assign tbxInvites# = Invites.  This is the idea but obviously won't work:

```
For DBNum = 0 to 6
frm.tbxInvites & DBNum = Invites
Next DBNum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frm.tbxInvites & DBNum` will give you a string, not a text box object.  However, you can use a string to reference a control as member of your form's `Controls` collection.

```vb
For DBNum = 0 to 6
    'frm.tbxInvites & DBNum = Invites
    Me.Controls("tbxInvites" & DBNum).Value = Invites
Next DBNum
```